# How do I get fix the SMTP Error: data not accepted error?

Tags: php, email, smtp

I am trying to send mass e-mails via PHPList software with the Direct Mail service in Alibaba Cloud, but I am getting the error below.

> Error sending email to email@gmail.com SMTP Error: data not accepted.SMTP server error: DATA command failed Detail: Invalid rcptto [@sm070102] at DATA State(Connection IP address:111.111.11.11) ANTISPAM_BAT[01201311R166c, ay35sg011193009126]: invaddr reject SMTP code: 559

What should I do to fix this problem?

Comment: If you get an error from the SMTP, contact the service provider and ask them. We can't know if they have specific rules. It looks like it could be some antispam-protection that's blocking you.

Comment: The `Invalid rcptto` and 559 sound like receipt email address in invalid. Are you sure the email address you are trying to send to is valid?

Comment: @user3783243 Yes, I'm sure the email is valid.